# How to make Sass watch css if files are being edited on the server?

Tags: bash, shell, sass, watch

I understand how to make a sass file watch a css file through the terminal. 
But this is only the case when the files are on my computer.

How to set up the same process if I'm editing files directly on the server.
When creating a website (I'm loading the files from the server on Sublime Text3) and I don't have any files on my computer and I don't want them on my computer either. I have no idea how to make sass watch my css file if the files are loaded directly on my text editor and saving everything directly on my server (so without saving anything on my computer).

If this is done through the terminal or any other way,, how is this done?

Comment: What are you currently using on your development machine to 'watch' sass? I can provide suggestions for your server setup based on your current implementation. Also, it is important to know if you are serving these files after running through the sass compilers, so I can provide suggestions for cache busting. Finally, what framework are you using, if any?

Comment: I would very much appreciate that! 
I'm using:
- Sublime text 3  as text-editor.
- Cute FTP (Paid Version) 
- Mac OSX 

And I've just recently learned how to set up Sass and work with it (still beginner level). But this is only setting it up when the files are on my pc. 
But no idea how to do it if the files are on the server and I'm editing them directly on the server.  Thx

Comment: Ok, so originally I thought your goal was to build a web app to handle live compiling of assets from users. But it sounds like you are just getting started. First, I'd suggest not editing files directly on the server because then you leave no room for testing before releasing. This is the concept of 'deploying' your code. So develop your sass/js/backend code in your development environment, then deploy it to your server after testing/making sure it all works and looks as you expected.

Comment: Fair enough, but I'm working on SubDomains regarding the deployment of my website. It's purely for testing purposes and meant as a learning trajectory. So if you could help me set it up, I will be very thankful as I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: No worries, I completely understand how deploying your code can be confusing. I just need a little more information about your current setup and knowledge in order to better help you. What is your server OS? Did you set up your server yourself? Do you have terminal access to it? Are you using Apache or Nginx to serve your files?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply (I hadn't noticed you replied). 

CENTOS 6.6 i686 kvm – server1  WHM 11.46.2 (build 4)
On the top left it says: WHM VPS optimized

I didn't set it up myself. I'm running it with a friend of mine who knows how to run it a bit better than me, but he has no clue either how it set up Sass. 

As far as I know I don't have terminal access to it. I have never accessed it through my terminal. 
How can I find out whether it's using Apache or Nginx? Sorry for the stupid questions!

Comment: I'm logged in my server and can possibly change the settings if you guide me through it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many hours and having squared eyes now, I managed to find a blog with a solution.
Here is the blog:

(1) . http://blog.omgmog.net/post/getting-started-with-using-sass-in-your-existing-website/

Long story short: I got it to work and to do what I want it to do! smile

I went through the steps as mentioned in the blog. In order to make it work I had to download a php file, which can be found here: (2) . http://leafo.net/scssphp/

In addition I had to create another php file and add some code into it (which can also be found in the second link).

Afterwards I had to link to the php file I had created and specified the .scss file to load (normally you don't link it to any php and you would specify it to the .css file).

The blog in link one explains everything in clear steps. Hope this helps others as well as I didn't see this question being answered anywhere before on StackOverflow!

Comment: Nice find. You may run into caching issues if you are not visually seeing updates after you save your scss on your server. To circumvent that, you'll want to implement a cache buster. There are many ways to do it, but since your still learning, I would choose the simplest revision method,  via a [query string](http://twosixcode.com/notes/view/simple-cache-busting-for-css-and-js). For more advanced options/automation, you might want to look into [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) for your sass/js/asset compilation and [revisioning](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-rev). It works very well.

Comment: Thx! I didn't know there was such a thing like a cache buster. Thx for that!
Gulp is very interesting, but as you pointed out i'm just starting with Sass and I'm trying to combine it with Bootstrap and soon Wordpress. 
But Gulp is definitely high on my "read more about"-list.

I'm wondering though if there is no other way to get this done without the PHP file?

Comment: Yes, you definitely can do exactly what you are currently doing without the php file. By avoiding run-time compilation of your assets, you would be doing what is know as 'asset-precompilation' which is where gulp excels. Your work flow would change to: 1) create scss/js locally like you currently do. 2) set up gulp to 'watch' this local directory where your scss files are located. Now 'on save' of any file, you would tell gulp to: compile your assets locally and then save your updated files to your 'deploy(Cute FTP) directory.' 3.) Cute FTP would then handle your uploads (however you see fit).

Comment: So you're saying that with Gulp, I can make an automated process and tell it with a piece of code:  first do step one, then two, then three etc. 
And it would be the same as if I was doing it locally without the php file and fully automated?

Comment: yep :) that's it! But honestly, you really don't want to automate a deployment 'on save' of a file...that's some bold live coding, and I definitely don't recommend it.

Comment: Thank you this explains a lot for me!